How to extract hex file from working MKR Zero
I have an Arduino MKR Zero which has working code on it, but I've lost the source. Is there a way that I can download the hex file from it, and then how can I upload it to a second so that I then have 2 working boards?
Thanks.

The Arduino MKR Zero appears to use the "Arm® Cortex®-M0 32-bit SAMD21" processor from Microchip. Usually to read everything in a processor's memory for copying to another requires the OEM's hardware and software tools. Providing the original programmer did not activate any type of "do not allow reading" feature in the processor. I'm posting as a comment as someone may know a less expensive/easier way to use the embedded Arduino firmware to read the processors program memory.

Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- Without the same hardware, I refrain to write an actual answer. However, read the documentation of the tool that the IDE uses to upload the compiled sketch. I'm pretty sure it can download the binary. You might need to use the command line. -- If you succeed, please write an own answer and mark it.
